# I am trying provider, it seams everything fine, but the textField text is not updating in my text widget

Tags: flutter, provider, state-management

I am practicing the state management. I am trying to update my textField (First class) to the TextWidgetwhich was in the Second() class. I don't know what problem i have made here?

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<Data>(
      create: (context) => Data(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: First(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My First Class

```
class First extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
          children: [
            TextField(
              onChanged: (value) {
                Provider.of<Data>(context).changeString(value);
              },
            ),
            Second(),
          ],
}
```

The Second Class

```
class Second extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return 
        Text(
          Provider.of<Data>(context).text,
        );
  }
}
```

My Data class which extends ChangeNotifier

```
class Data extends ChangeNotifier {

  String text = 'Type Something';

  void changeString(String newText) {
    text = newText;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a consumer to rebuild your widget with the new data.

```
Consumer<Data>(
          builder: (context, value, _) => Text(
          Provider.of<Data>(context).text,
        );
```